# JavaScript Google analytics within PHP

Tags: php, xml, google-analytics

I have a file which has pure PHP code, no HTML, the code generates an XML, I want google analytics for this file, to see how many requests are made. How can I do this?

if I do so for example:

```
<?php

include ("analyticsTracking.php"); / / analyticsTracking contains the code from google
...

?>
```

and then execute the code that generates my XML does not work, instead of printing it prints an XML like an ordinary HTML but without my tags.

How do I implement this?

Comment: Are you wanting to log using PHP or Javascript? A quick Google search came up with [this](https://code.google.com/p/php-ga/) to allow logging within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

assuming what you are serving is an XML document, there is no way to include google analytics to it, because it requires Javascript / HTML.

If the XML is passed through XSLT, the you can probably add the GA code to the footer when it is transformed to HTML.

Comment: actually a mobile application makes a request and the php code generates an XML return. There is no way to notify the analytics?

Comment: not from the php part of the code, no. you can send an event from the mobile application though. or you can implement a simple counter yourself, to read/write the access count to a file. that's extremely poor compared to GA data though.